# Created Event Not Visible in Google Calendar Google Api Client Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

i am using service account auth2client.service_account and googleapiclient to connect to google calendars and create events, my issue is my events are creating and also confirmed using list events, but the events are not being visible in google calendars.

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'chat-json.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

@app.route('/add_event/', methods=['POST'])
def add_event():
    # Authenticate using service account credentials
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    
    event = {
        'summary': 'Test Meeting',
        'location': 'Test Location',
        'description': 'Test Description',
        'start': {
            'dateTime': (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)).isoformat(),
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1, hours=1)).isoformat(),
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },
    }

    print(event)

    try:
        # Insert the event into the calendar
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
        print(event)
        return jsonify({'status': 'success', 'eventId': event['id']})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'status': 'error', 'message': str(e)})
```

```
Default guest permissions
Add invitations to my calendar
When I respond to the invitation in email
```

Sample of one of the event created, when go to html link it gives no requested event found

```
{'kind': 'calendar#event', 'etag': '"34578432000"', 'id': 'j4clmqbhch2d0k', 'status': 'confirmed', 'htmlLink': 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ajRjbG1xYmhjZ2ZwZW01ODE3MzBraDJkMGsgY2hhdC1haUBwcm8tcGFyay00MTc2MDguaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20', 'created': '2024-03-18T20:29:49.000Z', 'updated': '2024-03-18T20:29:49.216Z', 'summary': 'Python Meeting', 'description': 'A meeting to discuss Python projects.', 'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103', 'creator': {'email': 'example@pro-park-4178.iam.gserviceaccount.com', 'self': True}, 'organizer': {'email': 'example@pro-park-4178.iam.gserviceaccount.com', 'self': True}, 'start': {'dateTime': '2024-03-20T03:29:47Z', 'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2024-03-20T04:29:47Z', 'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'}, 'iCalUID': 'j4clmqbk@google.com', 'sequence': 0, 'reminders': {'useDefault': True}, 'eventType': 'default'}
```

I can't find what the issue is, is it in the configurations or permissions.

Comment: Have you configured domain wide deligation to the workspace account.   Also I can see where you are denoting the user on your domain to impersonate.  Where is that part of the code

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the same question and then i realized i was looking at the year 2015 because google calendar docs were written in 2015 and examples were using year 2015 so you might wanna check that.

If this doesn't solve your problem then make sure your calendar is displayed(that little checkbox on the left side of your calendar should be checked).

Good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).